# PC freezing upon booting/installing windows 10 or BIOS update

Tags: freeze

Today I replaced my old i3 8100 for an i7 9700K but I had to unplug everything from my motherboard in order to install my cooler master 212 evo cooler.

However, upon trying to boot to windows, the PC froze on the welcome screen that appears after entering your password for windows 10 and it would not move after that. So I restarted the power to my PC

Upon the second boot, I was greeted with a message asking me to repair windows and reset it. So I went through the reset process but it froze once again before the process could even get past 0%. When I say freeze, I mean everything freezes. The little loading icon does not even move. A few more power resets and boots, later I came to realize this problem would not just go away.

At this point I believed it must be the BIOS that was out of date. So, I created a bootable USB drive that had the correct BIOS files so I could install the update. However, once getting to the M FLASH screen where I select the file needed for the bios, it would freeze once again, but this time after about 2 minutes, the computer would completely power down and then power on by itself where it then booted to the BIOS which, of course, was not updated like I wanted to. My cpu temp before the freeze was 50c

Specs:

MSi Z370 A PRO motherboard

16gb ddr4 ram

Nvidia GTX 1660ti (not oc)

Intel core i7 9700k

EVGA 500w psu

Seagate 2tb barracuda hdd

Comment: Does it work if you put the old processor back in?

Comment: @Mokubai I will try this tomorrow as it is late right now. Will update

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of Windows had one license per PC, so large changes in hardware might have been seen as seen as a different PC. That is not the case for Windows 10, AFAIK.

However, you would likely need different drivers installed for the I7, which would *not* be on the original installation disk. Download the [Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) with the Media Creation Tool and try reinstalling from a USB.

You can also try running a live Linux distro, e.g. [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), without needing to install it. If it runs from USB, you know the I7 was installed correctly. For that matter, you might like to install it on the HDD, if it works well for you.

Comment: This is no longer a likely scenario as it *used to be*.  Even then, windows would blue screen if it didn't have the correct I/O drivers, not lock up (with  0x0000007B INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE to be specific).  This is something else (like memory timing or ??).  To be honest @DrMoishePippik .. this was my first thought too.. but now I can move windows disks between completely different hardware platforms and it still boots (with SVGA and a generic IO controller)

Answer (score 0):

I put back my intel i3 8100 and downloaded the bios update needed for the i7 9700k. Slapped in the i7 and it works fine now